# Websphere 8.5 ServletContextListener not invoked

Tags: java, websphere-8, servletcontextlistener

1. I want to load some data after the application start.
2. I use ServletContextListener to implement

***ServletStartListener.java***

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
public class ServletStartListener implements ServletContextListener {


    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory
            .getLog(ServletStartListener.class);
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        //  load data here 
        
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }
}
```

***web.xml***

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.config.ServletStartListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When I started the application at Websphere, the contextInitialized method wasn't invoked.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357661/servletcontextlistener-does-not-execute-on-deployment

Comment: I saw this solution,  it means that if I not change the configuration  the method will be invoked when the first request arrive . But my application never execute even there is many request.

Comment: I think if you introduce this configuration change the only part which is effected by this will be the time of your "contextInitialized" method execution. Instead of being executed with the first request it will be executed during the boot. ServletContext is created once per web application. So it won't effect your application in any other way.